# How to make Mathematica returns the exact expression I typed

Tags: evaluation, formatting, syntax

I'm using *Mathematica* to compare some constants. Before playing around with those constants, I would like to check that I didn't make any mistake in typing them. So my question is the following: "What is the command that return the expression I typed?"

Just to be clear. The expression

```
4*Sum[Log[Gamma[k]], {k, 3, IntegerPart[n] + 2*(n - IntegerPart[n])}]
```

returns:

[image]

And that is what I want. On the other hand, the expression

```
Sum[(2*n - 2*m - 1)*Log[n*(m + 1)], {m, 0, IntegerPart[n] - 1}]
```

returns:

[image]

and that is what I want to avoid!

Comment: You can use `Hold` and its variants.

Comment: And it's best to post code, so people can copy/paste and try for themselves.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply! I'm sorry for non-posting code. I'll keep it in mind for next questions.

Comment: Just edit the question and paste in the actual code.  This makes for a better question and a better site.

Comment: @Jagra You're definitely right! I edited my question, is it fine now? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is probably `HoldForm` but I don't understand why you cannot just check what you *typed* and why you need it to be printed again:

```
HoldForm[Sum[(2 n - 2 m - 1)*Log[n (m + 1)], {m, 0, IntegerPart[n] - 1}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for! At the beginning I was trying to do that because it's just simpler to check long expression in the form I'm used to do that. After I while I was just refusing to believe that there wasn't a proper command on Mathematica (I could't find it googling around)!

Comment: Welcome to the **20K club**.  Congratulations! :-)

Answer (score 6):

What you could do is

```
SetOptions[Sum, Method -> None]
```

Then

```
Sum[(2 n - 2 m - 1)*Log[n (m + 1)], {m, 0, IntegerPart[n] - 1}]
```

does not evaluate, similar to like @halirutans solution.
The advantage is that you can control this globally and do not have to put 
HoldForm everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In this specific case I'm fine with the "local" solution, but it's good to have another tool at disposal if needed.